# SetState of the selected option in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code looks like

```
placeholder="select banana or apple or cat" 

options=[
    {label : "Apple", value=2},
    { label : "Banana", value=3 },
    { label : "Cat", value=5}
]

value = { this.state.selectedOptions}
isSearchable={false}
isDisabled={this.state.isEdit === true}
```

and an onChange event.
I am having an array called "result" which is storing a property called "list". This list is an array that contains "Entity-Type". If the Entity-type is 2 I should get Apple, if it's 3 I should get Banana, If it's 5 I should get cat. I need to set the state to map my options and Entity-Type. I don't know how to do that as I am new to react.
I am able to see the Entity-Type in my response tab in dev tools but I am not seeing the selected option in my UI. I can see the option that I selected in before saving the package but after saving the package, whenever I want to Edit it I can see only placeholder there that is disabled. My package should have only one type of option. I have a heads up that is I should use result.list[0].EntityType.value
for mapping.

Comment: try hard code the value then see if the value remains like value = {label : "Banana", value=3}. If the value remains then the issue may be in your onChange event where you are setting the value. or your useState is not storing full object

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get u

Comment: It would be better if you share all the code

Comment: I should write it now based on the above requirement.